# Does installing MySQL with homebrew include the Workbench and GUI (is it preferred to install native)?

Tags: mysql, macos

Does installing MySQL with homebrew include MySQL workbench and GUI as if you were to run the Native installer (to be able to start and stop services)? I am trying to decide whether it is better to install using homebrew or with native.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Homebrew install does not include Workbench. The download and install of Workbench on OSX is pretty painless (a download and copy - no installer).

Here is some nice info on using Homebrew to install mysql http://blog.joefallon.net/2013/10/install-mysql-on-mac-osx-using-homebrew/

Answer (score 43):

homebrew mysql does not contain mysqlworkbench. Mysqlworkbench is another recipe that it is not exactly in homebrew but in homebrew cask (manager for GUI installs).

For GUI installs and 'other licence' installs there is a homebrew related package manager called homebrew cask.

You can find the caskroom recipes from homebrew,

```
$ brew search mysql
automysqlbackup
mysql ✔
mysql++
mysql-cluster
mysql-connector-c
mysql-connector-c++
mysql-sandbox
mysql-search-replace
mysqltuner              
homebrew/php/php53-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/php/php55-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/versions/mysql51
homebrew/versions/mysql56
Caskroom/cask/mysqlworkbench                 
homebrew/php/php54-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/php/php56-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/versions/mysql55
Caskroom/cask/mysql-utilities
Caskroom/cask/navicat-for-mysql
```

but for install them you need to install cask.

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask search mysql
brew cask install mysqlworkbench
```

The workbench is installed in /opt so unless the installer makes an alias to Applications you are not going to find it easily.

NOTE: As of March 2018, the brew installer does make an alias to the Applications folder, so no further action is required.

If you are unable to see it in the Applications folder, you should follow the following:

In my installation the mysqlworkbench was not aliased to /Applications, but in the workbench folder there is a symlink to the Application folder so it is easy to create the link yourself.

```
$ ll /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/mysqlworkbench/6.3.6
total 224
lrwxr-xr-x  1 pmg  staff      14 31 Jan 11:55 Applications -> /Applications/
drwxr-xr-x  3 pmg  staff     102 10 Dec 14:55 MySQLWorkbench.app
-rw-r--r--@ 1 pmg  staff  107640 10 Dec 14:55 background.tiff
```

make the alias

```
cd /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/mysqlworkbench/6.3.6/
ln -s MySQLWorkbench.app Applications
```

You can run the application now from Apps

Comment: As of March 2018, you no longer have to manually create the link, it just appears in the Applications folder.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to know which versions are available for MySQL:

- brew search mysql

You get to know know the versions as it will display after execution of the above command. For example I get this in console: `mysql@5.6`. There may be multiple versions, so choose accordingly.

Then execute the below command:

- brew install mysql@5.6

After installing MySQL, start the services of `mysql` using the below command:

- brew services start mysql@5.6

After the service has started, install `mysqlworkbench` using the below command:

- brew cask install mysqlworkbench

To update the current MySQL installation:

- brew upgrade mysqlworkbench